# Achartengine horizontal bar onclick issue

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

I m implemeting the Horizontal Barchart using achartengine, it will show properly in chart area but when I click on any bar it will not give me the value of that selected bar.The seriesselction will be null.Please find the code below and suggest me were m doing wrong.

```
private String[] mMonth = new String[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
int[] x = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
int[] income = { 100, 200, 370, 450, 500, 600, 700, 800 };
public static final String TYPE = "type";
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = getDemoDataset();
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = getDemoRenderer();
private GraphicalView mChartView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xy_chart);
     if (mChartView == null) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
            mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this, mDataset,
                    mRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);
            mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(100);
            layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        } else {
            mChartView.repaint();
        }

        mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // handle the click event on the chart

                  SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
                  if (seriesSelection == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(NewTestHorizontal.this, "No chart element", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  } else {
                    // display information of the clicked point
                    Toast.makeText(
                            NewTestHorizontal.this,
                        "Chart element in series index " + seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex()
                            + " data point index " + seriesSelection.getPointIndex() + " was clicked"
                            + " closest point value X=" + seriesSelection.getXValue() + ", Y="
                            + seriesSelection.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }

            }
        });

}

private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getDemoRenderer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
      incomeRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(130, 130, 230));
        incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
        incomeRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
        incomeRenderer.setChartValuesSpacing(15);
        incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        incomeRenderer.setChartValuesTextAlign(Align.CENTER);

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        multiRenderer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        multiRenderer.setXLabels(1);
        multiRenderer.setYLabels(0);
        multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.9f);
        multiRenderer.setBarWidth(30);
        multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Income Chart");
        multiRenderer.setXTitle("Year 2013");
        multiRenderer.setYTitle("Amount in Dollars");
        multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        multiRenderer.setInScroll(true);
        multiRenderer.setShowGridY(true);
        //multiRenderer.setXLabelsPadding(10);
        multiRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(10);
        multiRenderer.setInScroll(true);
        multiRenderer.setXAxisMin(-0.5);
        multiRenderer.setXAxisMax(7);
        multiRenderer.setYAxisMin(10);

        multiRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(15);
        multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(10);
        multiRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        multiRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(15);
        multiRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {10, 20, 20, 10});

        multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(3000);
        multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        multiRenderer.setShowGridX(true);
        multiRenderer.setShowGridY(true);


        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, mMonth[i]);
        }

        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(incomeRenderer);
        return multiRenderer;
}

private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getDemoDataset() {
     XYSeries incomeSeries = new XYSeries("Income");
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            incomeSeries.add(i, income[i]);
        }

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(incomeSeries);
        return dataset;
}
```

}

Comment: The horizontal bar chart is an experimental one and it has some known issues: http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=203

Comment: Thanks Dan. An one more thing I want to ask can we change the color of selected bar chart(means if user select a particular bar so I want to change the color of that bar).

Comment: You can change the color of a bar only if it is in another series.

Comment: Ok Dan I will try that thanks you so much.If possible kindly provide the any reference for changing the color of bar. :) ones again thx for your time Dan.